# GRUB 2 menu is not showing Windows 8 in the menu when dual booting with Fedora 17 (32 Bit)

Tags: fedora, grub, grub2

I am successfully able to install *Fedora 17 (32 bit)* along with *Windows 8* on my system. But when I restart the system, the *GRUB 2* menu doesn't show the windows 8.

To troubleshoot the problem, I tried installing a third OS (Backtrack 5) on the system. And 
this time when I restarted the system, the *GRUB* menu listed all the three OS in the machine including Windows 8.

So, I figured out that there is a some problem with the *GRUB 2*. I am not sure though because for one of my friend(who by the way is using a 64 bit machine), the dual boot worked absolutely fine.

Anybody else who had experienced the same problem before or any idea what could be the reason behind this?

Comment: It was probably a one-time thing where the Grub menu didn't get updated properly. You could have tried repairing Grub instead of installing yet another OS.

Comment: I don't think so. I had the same problem with Fedora 18 and it was working fine on a 64 bit machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess there was some problem with the GRUB 2 in the 32 bit versions of Fedora 17 and 18. I tried the same with Fedora 19 and everything was working just fine. My GRUB menu is now showing all the operating systems on my Hard drive.